# How to access GitHub's repository by username and password with Aptana Studio?

Tags: github, aptana

I have been using git previously by hosting it myself and uploading my SSH key to the server.

This is the first time I am using Github and would like to link to it via username and password instead.

I have linked the project and when I try to pull, instead of asking for username and password, I get this error message:

```
/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/plugins/com.aptana.git.core_3.0.0.1350339236/os/linux/askpass.tcl: 3: exec: wish: not found
error: unable to read askpass response from '/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/plugins/com.aptana.git.core_3.0.0.1350339236/os/linux/askpass.tcl'
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

Where do I setup the username and password?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 'exec: wish: not found' part of the error means tk and python-tk packages are missing.

### Quick fix

Install tk and python-tk packages.

### Long fix

Access the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> OR <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to return back, out of tty, to Gnome).

From the terminal, type the following:

```
sudo apt-get install tk && sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

Once installed, try push/pull git again via Aptana Studio (Click the 'clogs' icon > push/pull). This time you should hopefully be presented with a password entry query.

Source: [Problems cloning a GitHub repo using Egit on Eclipse 3.6.2 Helios](http://www.only10types.com/2011/11/problems-cloning-github-repo-using-egit.html)